# PLINQO Stop generation on build class library

Tags: codesmith, plinqo

I've just started using PLINQO which looks really good so far.

The only problem I have is whilst I'm doing custom amends on the entities I rebuild the contained class library and codesmith wants to regenrate my class library which prompts the visual studio message. "Your project has been amend outside, do you want to reload?" etc..

Can you turn this off? And if I do want to regenarate I can just right click the csp file?

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are placing your code inside of the partial class that has the meta data class then your changes will be preserved. Are you generating from within Visual Studio? You would need to turn generate on build off by right clicking on the csp.

Yes, it is safe to right click the csp to generate.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski

Comment: Thanks Blake, That's exactly what I needed... How did I miss that! :)